# getElementsByTagName is not finding "Input" or "td" tag with ID in it

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I'm attempting to navigate a webpage in IE11. The page is internal work related so I cannot share the page. I have navigated multiple pages from the site without any issue, until I have reached a date field that I want to enter a specific date in.

I can't seem to find the element. I've tried a few approaches that I'm aware of, but my most recent attempts are below. You will notice that I must use a wildcard `*` for the ID since the series of numbers after `"txtDate"` always changes.

Searching for tag `input` and a wildcard ID:

```
    For Each ee In ieApp.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If ee.ID Like "txtDate*" Then
            ee.Value = dt
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ee
```

Searching for tag `td` and a `ClassName` of `"clsSelectDateEditBox"`:

```
    For Each ee In ieApp.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If ee.ClassName = "clsSelectDateEditBox" Then
            ee.Value = dt
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ee
```

With both of these, many `input` or `td` tags are found, but none with the `ID` or `ClassName` I'm calling out. Could it be because it seems to be within a table?

In a desperation attempt, I tried simply finding the `ID` without searching through tags.

```
ieApp.Document.all.Item("txtDate*").Value = dt
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. I've hit a wall with this element although the website was so simple up to this point.

Below is the html. The part I'm looking for is towards the bottom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="viewer" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    input {
      font-size: 9pt;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    body,
    textarea,
    input,
    select {
      font-family: Tahoma, arial, geneva, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .clsSelectDateEditBox {
      padding: 0px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      width: auto;
      min-width: 140px;
    }
    
    table {
      empty-cells: hide;
    }
    
    *>.clsPromptComponent {
      display: inline-table;
    }
    
    .ls,
    .sc,
    .xt,
    .rt,
    .tb,
    .ccb {
      font-style: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: medium;
      word-spacing: normal;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: none;
      text-align: left;
      text-indent: 0px;
      line-height: normal;
      white-space: normal;
      word-wrap: initial;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .pg *,
    .pp * {
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .pg *,
    .pp * {
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .clsPromptComponent {
      display: inline;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: left;
      clear: none;
    }
    
    .clsPromptComponent,
    .clsDisplayInline,
    .clsFieldSet {
      display: -moz-inline-grid;
    }
    
    .pg,
    .pp {
      font-family: Tahoma, "Arial Unicode MS", "Andale WT", Arial, "MS UI Gothic", Gulim, SimSun, PMingLiU, Raghu8, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .pg,
    .pp,
    .tb,
    .rt,
    .sc,
    .ls,
    .xt {
      color: #000000;
    }
    
    .pg,
    .pp,
    .tb,
    .rt,
    .sc {
      font-size: 10pt;
    }
    
    .py {
      height: 100%;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding: 3px 5px;
    }
    
    .pp {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .RVReport {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .RVContent {
      overflow: auto;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 0px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .mainViewerTD {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .mainViewerTable {
      border-spacing: 0;
      border: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    body>form>.mainViewerTable {
      border-spacing: 0;
      border: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    .formWarpRequest {
      margin: 0px;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow: auto;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body.viewer {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    html.viewer {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="viewer" role="document" aria-label="IBM Cognos Viewer" onclick="if (typeof window.oCV_NS_ != 'undefined'){window.oCV_NS_.rvMainWnd.hideOpenMenus();}">
  <form name="formWarpRequest_NS_" class="formWarpRequest" id="formWarpRequest_NS_" role="form" aria-label="Hidden main form" action="/sci/bi/v1/disp" method="post">
    <table class="mainViewerTable" id="mainViewerTable_NS_" role="presentation">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="mainViewerTR_NS_">
          <td class="mainViewerTD">
            <div class="RVContent" id="RVContent_NS_" lang="en-us" style="position: relative;" name="RVContent_NS_">
              <div class="RVReport" id="CVReport_NS_" role="main">
                <table class="pp" id="rt_NS_" onmousemove="if (typeof window.oCVSC_NS_ != 'undefined') window.oCVSC_NS_.pageHover(event);" onkeydown="window.oCV_NS_.onKeyDown(event);" onclick="window.oCV_NS_.rvMainWnd.pageClicked(event);" ondblclick="if (typeof window.oCVSC_NS_ != 'undefined') window.oCVSC_NS_.pageDoubleClicked(event);"
                  oncontextmenu="window.oCV_NS_.dcm(event, true)" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" lid="Prompt Page_NS_">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="py">
                        <table class="tb" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <div class="clsPromptComponent" id="PRMT_N0x14614ec0x0x12a8b83c_NS_">
                                  <table role="presentation" style="vertical-align: top; display: inline;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>
                                          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td><input class="clsSelectDateEditBox" id="txtDateN0x14614ec0x0x12a8b83c_NS_" aria-invalid="false" type="text" value=""></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Step through with F8 and check the result of Debug.Print ieApp.document.querySelectorAll(".clsSelectDateEditBox").Length   or  Debug.Print ieApp.document.querySelectorAll("[id^=txtDate]").Length

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I just did that and it always returned a "0". It sounds like it doesn't exist, although I'm looking right at it in the html?

Comment: In the browser itself how many matches do you get if you enter [id^=txtDate] in the elements tab search bar?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right when you say elements tab search bar, when I'm in the DOM Explorer and put that text into the Find bar it returns 1 match.

Comment: You have understood correctly. 1) Did you step slowly with F8 and still get 0 with the querySelectorAll lines? 2) Is the html you shared the entire page html?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Though what I'm attempting is further down in the html

Comment: Does the html for that element change when selected or interacted with?

Comment: Selected, no. But yes when interacting with. As I type in a date the class changes to `clsSelectDateEditBoxParseError` and also `aria-invalid="true"`. However, once I enter the date it reverts back to the same element as when the page first loads. I believe the change is because the date I'm entering is not yet a valid format when it is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I have created a sample using the following script, it works well on my side, you could check it:

```
Sub extractTablesData1()
    'we define the essential variables

    Dim IE As Object, Data As Object
    Dim ticket As String


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("<your website url>")    

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Set Data = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

        Debug.Print Data.Length

        If Len(Data) > 0 Then

            For Each ee In Data
                If ee.ID Like "txtDate*" Then
                    ee.Value = CStr(Now()) 'set value.
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next ee

            Debug.Print ee.ID

            'Data.Value = "Hello"           
        End If    
    End With    
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

The result like this:

[image]

Please try to clear the browser cache data, then, retest the code. If still not working, you could also try to use the getElementsByClassName method to get the elements. Like this:

```
    Set Data = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("clsSelectDateEditBox")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried this out and have interesting results. First, using the tag name returns a length of 47. I then stepped through the `For Each ee` loop and it never found an ID to match the criteria `IF ee.ID Like "textDate*" Then`. 
Then I switched the `Data` to use the ClassName and it returned a 0 length, which I dont understand why. 
I'm confused about why the `"txtDate*"` is not being found.

Comment: How about using this code `IF ee.ID Like "*textDate*"`? Which version of Excel (VBA) are you using? I'm using Excel 2016 version. Perhaps the issue is related to the Excel version.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, other work priorities came up. I also am using Excel 2016. Adding the extra wildcard * to make it `*textDate*` didn't seem to result in anything different. I'll keep playing with it, but I can't think of why this ID is not being found.

Comment: have you ever solved this issue? If still not solved, after using VBA script to open the IE instance, try to use F12 developer tools to check the elements, and check whether you could find this element and check the ID attribute, whether the value is correct?